# perl + DOM + use XML::LibXML + how to remove xml version title from XML file? with DOM

Tags: perl

I create the following XML file,  by perl script (Showing down) , using XML::LibXML:

```
 more test.xml 

 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <books>
 <computer/>
 </books>
```

My question: how to remove "xml version title":

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

from the test.xml file? With DOM commands in the perl script?

in order to get only the follwoing lines in the text.xml file:

```
 <books>
 <computer/>
 </books>
```

Yael

#

the perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc  = XML::LibXML::Document->new;  
my $root = $doc->createElement('books');
$doc->setDocumentElement($root);

my $computer = $doc->createElement('computer');
$root->appendChild($computer);
$doc->toFile('/var/tmp/test.xml');
```

Comment: Why? The values it specifies are the default, so the meaning of the data would be unchanged.

Comment: the values are only example
the main target of the question is to delete the xml version from test.xml file
yael

Comment: After reading the code I see that it should be possible to set a variable `$skipXMLDeclaration` to 1. However I don't seem to know enough about scoping etc. so I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: sorry but its not delete the xml version -:( , maybe I not define it right in the script?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, regarding my previous comment, I now found a solution.

It seems `toFile` bypasses `$skipXMLDeclaration` whereas `toString` doesn't. So the following works:

```
$XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration = 1;

my $doc  = XML::LibXML::Document->new;
# create your document

print $doc->toString;
```

The (very small) downside is that you have to write the file yourself.

Comment: THX can you please advice the best way to print $doc->toString; to file ( in order to save in the file the XML doc?
yael

Comment: C'mon, this isn't hard. You just open a file handle and print to it... `open my $fh, '>', $filename; print $fh $doc->toString; close $fh;`

Comment: Very strange fact: If you turn it of, it somehow also disables pretty printing. WTF. :(

Comment: For me adding ```$XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration = 1;``` causes wide character warnings...

Answer (score 0):

Alas, the issue becomes much more serious when one has UTF-8 input.

```
$ cat x
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use XML::LibXML;
local $XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration = 0;
if (pop) {
    binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
    $XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration = 1;
}
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new( '1.0', "UTF-8" );
my $P   = $doc->createElement('P');
my $Q   = $doc->createElement('Q');
$P->appendText("中文");
$Q->appendChild($P);
$doc->setDocumentElement($Q);
print $doc->toString(1);
$ ./x 0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Q>
  <P>中文</P>
</Q>
$ ./x 1; echo
<Q><P>中文</P></Q>
$ ./x 0 |fgrep -v \?xml
<Q>
  <P>中文</P>
</Q>
```

Above you can observe that the best one can do, even after hacking
around the charset ramifications, is surrender ones formatting, if one
doesn't want the xml header.

Therefore I conclude the only answer that is surefire, is to pipe the
output to `fgrep -v \?xml` !