# Perl XML::LibXML exclude xml doctype

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I'm using XML::LibXML to parse an xml file and change values of new nodes and writing back. The original file does not contain doctype but when I write back to the file, the library adds doctype as <?xml version="1.0" ?> at the top of the file.
 My client is not happy about it. Is there a way I can turn off/exclude the doctype other than using toString method and stripping it out?

```
my $string= $doc->toString();
$string =~ s/<\?xml.*\?>\n//sm;
```

Comment: [perl + DOM + use XML::LibXML + how to remove xml version title from XML file? with DOM][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236028/perl-dom-use-xmllibxml-how-to-remove-xml-version-title-from-xml-file-wi

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of `skipXMLDeclaration` as gangabass mentioned in comment. Take a look at http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML#Serialization for more options.